# Locating HVAC breaker in box

Tags: hvac, circuit-breaker

I'm replacing my thermostat in the home but my breaker box does not identify which breaker.  How can I locate the breaker? Thanks

Comment: Which breaker turns off the furnace/air-handler?

Comment: Thermostats are powered by 24 volts AC and the power behind it cannot hurt you. However, they caution you to turn the power off in the instructions as an extra safety measure.

Answer (score 2):

If you kill the power to the furnace and A/C you kill the power to the thermostat

Comment: The thermostat is typically powered by a 24v transformer attached to or near your furnace.  It will be on the same circuit as the furnace.